# `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError) in postfix aliases

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, postfix-mta, aliases

I got below error when sending mail from postfix.

> Command output:
>   /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)

I have created aliases to send mail. In aliases,

```
user:"|/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby /home/ruby/my_project_path/app/models/get_mail.rb"
```

When I run this command in terminal, it runs successfully. But not in postfix aliases.

In `get_mail.rb`, I used
`require 'mail'`

Answer (score 1):

You can output $LOAD_PATH at console. If path not include, you have to add abs path.

Comment: thank you for reply.i run $LOAD_PATH command but not display any output.what it means??? path not include.

Comment: You can execute `puts $LOAD_PATH` at irb.
You will be seen path, check out file if include your file absolute path or directory.

Comment: puts $LOAD_PATH output is:
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0   
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux   
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby   
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0   
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux  
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby  
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0  
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux

Comment: And then your lib mail whether in under these directory ?

Comment: i didn't find lib mail in any of them.but when i run "which mail" command then output is /bin/mail.

Comment: So you need to install mail gem. https://github.com/mikel/mail
I didn't know your mail script, Whether or not  is ruby lib?
But if you want to use syntax like `require "xxxx" `, It's have to include  $LOAD_PATH dir.

Comment: my mail script is:    #! /usr/local/bin/ruby
# coding: utf-8
#------------------------------------------------
# Ruby script to get a mail via alias of postfix.
#-------------------------------------------------
require "mail"

class GetMail
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
     mail = Mail.new do
      from     'xyz@gmail.com'
      to       'abc@gmail.com'
      subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
      body     'Body'
     end

      mail.delivery_method :sendmail
      mail.deliver
  end
end

GetMail.new.execute

Comment: You need to change your ruby path. Don't use system ruby.
At your home dir execute `which ruby`. Then change `#! /usr/local/bin/ruby`.

Comment: i changed ruby path,but same result.

Comment: Is these execute file?
when I run `require 'mail' ` is return true. And test your file is successful.
But I use rbenv to manage lib. maybe to restart terminal or check out your rvm?

Comment: yes,my file is executable.And when i run require 'mail' in console then it return true.

Comment: Are you execute `./get_mail.rb` successful? 
if not success the problem maybe is rvm, the other is ruby version.
My ruby version is 2.1.3.

Comment: yes it run successfully in console ./get_mail.rb. not working in aliases,may be   ruby version problem.